# Can not get Nuxt.js configuration for Axios to work

Tags: javascript, vue.js, axios, nuxt.js

I am using Nuxt.js first time now. However I struggle with using the `axios` module of it somewhat. I like the fact that I can configure the baseUrl in the `nuxt.config.js` file. I expect. So this is what I did:

```js
// nuxt.config.js
  ...
  axios: {
    baseUrl: 'http://localhost:3001',

    publicRuntimeConfig: {
      axios: {
        browserBaseURL: "http://localhost:3004"
      }
    },

    privateRuntimeConfig: {
      axios: {
        baseURL: "http://localhost:3005"
      }
    },
  },
  modules: [
    '@nuxtjs/axios',
    '@nuxtjs/auth-next',
    '@nuxtjs/proxy'
  ],
  ...
```

Here comes my vue components method I declared to use the Nuxt.js axios module (using `this.$axios.$get` insteand of `this.$axios.get`). However I am not sure if there is a difference using `this.$axios` and just `$axios.` the latter is called a "plugin" according to the documentation. I did not manage to get axios working with only calling `$axios` - it can't be resolved so I stick with `this.$axios`.

Anyway here is method code containing the axios get call. As you can see I am omitting the base url `https://localhost` since I expect it to be prepended through the `nuxt.config.js` configuration.

```js
    updateTeams: function () {
      this.$axios.$get('/api/teams')
        .then(({data}) => {
          this.teams = data
        }).catch((error) => {
        console.error(error)
      })
    }
```

The result is disappointing. The call is still done with `http://localhost:3000` instead of one of the others I configured in the `nuxt.config.js` file. I rechecked the documentation twice but could not find any hint what I am doing wrong.

```
Request URL: http://localhost:3000/api/teams
```